# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dist/index.html'

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

So, I've been trying for days to get a angular universal app running but I keep getting this issue when I try to run the server like

```
npm run dev:ssr
```

I have set my server.ts file as in the below link
https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts

My server.ts file is as below

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// ssr DOM
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// index from browser build!
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
// for mock global window by domino
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
// from server build
const files = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/dist-server`);
// mock
global['window'] = win;
// not implemented property and functions
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
// mock documnet
global['document'] = win.document;
// othres mock
global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

my app.server.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

I am using Angular 9 and at a stage where I am thinking of dropping the idea of using angular universal at all. Seems it its way too unstable to be used at the moment.

Contents of dist folder:

[image]

Does anyone here have a solution to this?

Comment: Did you do a build before? And please show the content of the dist folder

Comment: @David - yes i did a npm run build:ssr before that. I have updated the question with the contents of dist folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incorrectly set the `distFolder` variable. The `distFolder` from `server.ts` must point to the files containing the client side app, which is `dist\YourProjectName\browser` in your app. Note that this configured in `angular.json` file.

To correct your error, try changing the `distFolder` path in your `server.ts`

```
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist','YourProjectName',  'browser');
```

Comment: did you mean i should change it here const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join('.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
?

Comment: I did not see that you blacked out part of the screenshot! Answer edited. If it still does not work, can you do a `console.log(indexHtml)` after that variable assignment?

Comment: Looks like that worked. But Im getting a new error now Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/mukeshsingh/Documents/My Websites/WokeCode2/WokeCode-SPA/dist-server'

Comment: I'm sorry but that was again a wrong directory issue. The app is finally up and running. Thanks a lot man. you saved it. For other: I had to change this:   const files = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/dist/{MyProjectName}-SPA/server`);

Comment: Glad I could help !